# How can I generate a web application client for a WSDL service?

Tags: soap, wsdl, code-generation

I'm trying to generate a quick website to allow a customer to access a SOAP service specified in WSDL. Any language/toolkit is ok.

Ideally I'd like to feed the WSDL file to a code generator and have it emit servlets/PHP/python, one URL per operation specified in the WSDL, with form fields equivalent to the attributes in the WSDL. The generated app would allow the user to fill in a form, submit the operation to the SOAP service, and return the result.

There's a website at http://www.soapclient.com/SoapTest.html that does almost exactly what I want to do, but they don't publish any source code.

Comment: @jmort253 that a rather strange question.

Comment: @jmort253 there is no obvious and simple answer that I'm aware of.

Comment: @Mk - I think you're right. I have seen things like what len is referring to before with SOAP webservices, but I'm not really a SOAP proponent so will bow out of this one. +1 to len.

Answer (score 0):

The website at http://www.soapclient.com/SoapTest.html was generated using this tool:  http://www.sqldata.com/SoapClient/soapclient30.htm

It's a Windows-only program, but the C++ code it generates might be fairly easy to port to another platform, or be translated to PHP, etc.